# Image print's but it stops every other thing

Tags: php

this is Index file , it's task is to provide values to the cover.php file and get the image in return...

```
<?php
require('cover.php');


                    $name="Tushar Kesarwani";
                    $id=112200333;
                    $dob="9/9/1990";
                    $email="tushar.kesarwani2@gmail.com";
                    $profilelink="http://www.facebook.com/iamtusharDOTcom";
                    $relationship= "single";


$me = imagecreatefrompng('me.png');


$ob= new createimage();
$ob->create($name,$id,$dob,$email,$profilelink,$relationship,$me);







?>
<h1>hdhdhdh</h1>
```

this is cover.php, it's task is to create a image

```
<?php
class createimage
{


    function create($name,$id,$dob,$email,$profilelink,$relationship,$me)
    {




                    $base = imagecreatefromjpeg('fb.jpg');
                    $white = ImageColorAllocate($base, 255, 255, 255); 

                    imagecopy($base, $me, 93, 102, 0, 0, imagesx($me), imagesy($me));

                    $font = 'ARIAL.TTF';
                    $font2='Cacophony Loud.ttf';
                    imagettftext($base, 25, 0, 228, 133, $white, $font2, $name);
                    imagettftext($base, 16, 0, 268, 183, $white, $font, $id);
                    imagettftext($base, 16, 0, 291, 224, $white, $font, $dob);
                    imagettftext($base, 13, 0, 126, 294, $white, $font, $email);
                    imagettftext($base, 13, 0, 126, 323, $white, $font, $profilelink);
                    imagettftext($base, 13, 0, 126, 353, $white, $font, $relationship);
                    // Output and free memory
                    header('Content-type: image/png');
                    imagejpeg($base);
                    imagedestroy($base);


    }

}


?>
```

The problem is that.. images is printing but  tag or anything after the image is not working

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're sending an actual image.  The header `image/png` is what is doing it.  If you want to set it as an `img`, save the file to the server and load it in the `src` attribute, or base64 encode it in the `src` attribute (properly)
To save it as an image do something to the tune of:

```
// Remove the proceeding line
// header('Content-type: image/png');
$name = '/location/where/you/want/to/save/file.jpg';
imagejpeg($base, $name);

echo "<img src='$name' />";
```

Also, you're sending headers for png files but you're creating a jpeg file.  You might want to correct that.

Comment: Yeah it Worked , but there is problem in this thing :(
This will be on server and many users will use the application at a same time;
however, this method saves the image on server.
so it might happen that at the same time 2 image created and thus overlapped :)

Comment: well, you could use a unique file names for all the images you generate, e.g. by using a hash of the ID :)